# Install script on non wordpress subdirectory folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

Im trying to install a script "moodle" in a subdirectory of my wordpress website but if I keep it in first level folder i get the wordpress 404 page not available or if I go deeper "2 level folders" it only show me my blog post!

however the url is changing to moodle/install.php !

How can I tell wordpress to ignore that specific subdirectory and everything inside it?  i did search and tried some of the .htaccess hits but non actually worked!

Comment: the install.php redirect should happen, that brings you through the web-based installer and will create the tables for your db.

Comment: it does redirect me but what I see is my wordpress blog not the new script installation!

Comment: try looking at your .htaccess in the moodle folder, if there isn't one make a basic one.  In your root wordpress directory, make sure you don't have `AllowOverride None` so that the basic one in the subdirectory can override it.  I've installed many things in subdirectories of wordpress before...if you're having trouble it's a system configuration or conflict between the 2 systems.

Comment: didnt find any! however I add AllowOverride All which didnt fix it but it prevented wp. anyway I rtied to install the script on different website in the same server but it didn't go through due to its requirement :(

Comment: My suggestion was to allow override on your wordpress .htaccess file, and then in your moodle folder put a simple htaccess and overwrite what your moodle folder is inheriting from wordpress.  Did you try that?  I did a quick search and moodle has a lot of issues being installed in subdirectories.  I don't know why that would be...but you might want to look in the moodle community since that seems to be the issue